# Rename columns based on another DataFrame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a DataFrame `dataframe1` with columns `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`.

I have another DataFrame `dataframe2` as below:

```
Old_Names New_Names
A    1st
B    2nd
C    3rd
D    4th
```

How do I use `dataframe2` to change the column names in `dataframe1` to `['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th']`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) function:

```
dataframe1.rename(columns=dataframe2.set_index('Old_Names')['New_Names'], inplace=True)
```

The `columns` argument can be dict-like or a function, and in this case a Series representing the names mapping is used.

Comment: Sorry, I get a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series'`, could u help?

Comment: I found the reason, it seems caused by duplicated entries in `dataframe2`.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use dataframe1.columns:

```
dataframe1.columns=dataframe2.columns.values
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using list comprehension

```
dataframe1 = [item for item in dataframe2]
```

now your dataframe1 will have the contents of dataframe2

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your columns with a list, so making a list of the new_name column will work.

```
>>> dataframe1.columns = list(dataframe2['New_Names'])
>>> print(list(dataframe1.columns)) #To intuitively show the columns are renamed
['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th']
```